# Can sunflower or coconut oil be substituted for vegetable shortening in cake icing?

Tags: baking, substitutions, frosting

I was reading [this recipe](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/what-kind-of-frosting-doesnt-need-to-be-refrigerated/4869#4869) for cake icing and was wondering what would happen if I substituted sunflower oil or coconut oil (which is thicker and may better model the texture of the shortening) for vegetable shortening. I don't eat vegetable shortening/margarine/crisco and am looking for a way to adapt this recipe.

```
4 lb powdered sugar
1 TB cream of tartar
1 1/4 c. of white shortening (crisco ... the sticks are easy to measure)
a pinch of salt
1 TB extract of your choice
3/4 to 1c. of water (maybe more depending on humidity)
```

> Put all ingredients except the water into a mixer. Add 3/4 c. water,
>   and slowly add more to make the consistancy of your choice. Mix on low
>   speed 'til mixed, then on #6 or 8 for 6 to 7 minutes. Consistency
>   should be "creamy" -- like cream cheese when soft. Stiff icing should
>   be creamy also.

Comment: I've been meaning to try my buttercream with coconut oil, if I give it a shot I'll report back

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure, as I've never tried, but I doubt it would whip up into the right texture. Shortening is already a solid, so you're just introducing air. Sunflower oil is a liquid, so you'd want to solidify it somehow to make frosting.

Comment: I was just going to edit the question to include coconut oil as another possible substitute - good thinking.

Comment: I think coconut oil would be fine.

Comment: I'd agree, coconut oil should work.  You might want to avoid virgin  coconut oil, though.  Its melting point is only about 80F, so it could wind up liquid if you're working in a hot kitchen, or if you'll be serving the cake in warm weather.