# At Home Cake Decorator

Tags: cake, decorating, frosting, dairy-free

So I have been researching how to become a home bakery. The laws are a little more restrictive than if I were to have a commercial kitchen. So I live in Arizona and one of the cottage rules is I can not make anything that needs to be refrigerated. Now, I love decorating and making cakes and cupcakes but I am unable to use frosting. Does anyone have good recipes for a non-refrigerated frosting? I am looking for all kinds of frosting. I am interested! Thank you!

Comment: the nature of the site kinda sucks, as this question has been asked before (maybe without your specifics with the commercial intent), but there’s no food way to flag it to see if people have updates years later.  But see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/4835/67

Comment: I made a note that my teacher was a professional in that other post… so it should get bumped to the front page so people see it.